Find the PID or name of the process that listens on a specific port
I'm on a Linux system with no network commands (e.g. netstat, ss, lsof, ...). There are some scripts in the directory (say /private) that I don't have permission to read and I don't even have permission to ls on the directory. I want to find the name of the script or process PID that listens on port 8000.
I used this but I don't get a response:
PORT=8000;find /proc -lname "socket:\[$(cat /proc/net/* | awk -F " " '{print $2 ":" $10 }' | grep -i `printf "%x:" $PORT` | head -n 1 | awk -F ":" '{print $3}')\]" 2> /dev/null | head -n 1 | awk -F "/" '{print "PID="$3}'

Any idea?

If you don't have root access and the process in port 8000 is not your own, trying to find the user/PID with find /proc -lname ... is futile: you don't have access to the /proc/<PID>/fd/ directories of any processes you don't own. Only the process owner or someone with root privileges can do that.

Also, processing all /proc/net/* files is overly broad: you probably want just /proc/net/tcp* and maybe /proc/net/udp*.

See How do I find out more about socket files in /proc/fd?

You have the right idea.
/proc/net/tcp[6] have the local <address>:<port> in second field, state in fourth (with 0A for TCP_LISTEN), and inode in 10th field with that same inode appearing the in the symlink target as socket:[<inode>].
In the end, it's just the joining of a few tables you want (those /proc/net/tcp*, the pid to socket-inode mapping and the process list with their args/name).
export PORT=8000
find /proc/*/fd -xtype s -printf '%H %l\n' 2> /dev/null |
  awk -F'[][/]' '{print $5,$3}' |
  sort -k1,1 |
  join - <(
    awk '$4 == "0A" && $2 ~ sprintf(":%04X$", ENVIRON["PORT"]) {
           print $10
         }' /proc/net/tcp* |
      sort
  ) |
  join -1 2 - <(
    ps -Ao pid= -o args= |
    sort -k1,1
  )

For me, that gives:
10763 86769 socat -u tcp-listen:8000,reuseaddr -

Where 10763 is the pid, 86769 the socket inode number.
Now, your approach should also give you the pid, even if in a less efficient way (I do get PID=10763 in my case). If it doesn't, one explanation would be that the process is running as a user other than you and you're not superuser. That would be the same with lsof/fuser/ss/netstat, what process fds are open to is private information.

sudo lsof -i tcp:8000 will show the information you want.

If you had read the question carefully, you would have noticed that I mentioned that these tools are not installed on the operating system :/
